# ViewPager returning wrong fragment

Tags: android

I want to use `ViewPager` to swipe through songs in my `Media Player` ( going forward or backward like SoundCloud app for android ).
I have created a fragment which I `inflate` and set inside information like song name, author etc.

I have read some topics on StackOverflow about the `ViewPager` displays wrong items ( [Viewpager shows wrong page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540320/viewpager-shows-wrong-page) and [Android Viewpager show wrong pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046889/android-viewpager-show-wrong-pages) and a lot more ) but I don't have fixed number of `XML`'s to use with the `ViewPager`.

My Data is displayed in a `RecyclerView`, when I am pressing the item on index 4 for example I call the following method:

```
       mPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

So the `mPager` is set to position 4.

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.i("TEST","Returnin a fragment on position "+position);
        return fragment = new MusicSliderFragment();
    }
```

But on my `Adapter` when it's changing I get the following output:

```
02-23 10:39:57.131 7599-7599/************** I/TEST: Returning a fragment on position 4
02-23 10:39:57.131 7599-7599/************** I/TEST: Returning a fragment on position 3
02-23 10:39:57.131 7599-7599/************** I/TEST: Returning a fragment on position 5
```

And when my application is launched I get the following output:

```
I/TEST: Returning a fragment on position 0
I/TEST: Returning a fragment on position 1
```

The main problem is when I am opening the app first time and set the song on position 4 the fragment information are displayed in the next fragment.

Is there a way how can I fix this?

Adapter Class:

```
 private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private MusicSliderFragment fragment;

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.i("TEST","Returnin a fragment on position "+position);
            return fragment = new MusicSliderFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

        public void updateSongName(String name) {
            fragment.setSongName(name);
        }
    }
```

The `RecyclerView` `Listener` :

```
            musicList.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, final int position) {

                        Log.i("TEST", "Setting the mPager position to: "+position);
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                    }
                }


And the `Listener` of the `mPager` where I update the song name for example:

mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                play(position);

                ScreenSlidePagerAdapter adapter = (ScreenSlidePagerAdapter) mPager.getAdapter();
                adapter.updateSongName(splitName(myDataList.get(position))[0]);

                Log.i("TEST", "Playing the position: "+position);
                mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you mean position four is fourth fragment? Does your index start from 0 or 1?

Comment: My position in Arrays and RecyclerView starts from 0, about the position of viewpager I think it starts from 0.

Comment: No it starts from 0 just set the position as 3 it should work for you.Let me know if that is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

View pager can load neighbour fragments when you choose current. Method setOffscreenPageLimit() defines how many neighbours you want to preload.
onPageSelected(int position) should work correct and returns current item.

Comment: So the viewpager load the page 4 and then load the neighbour ( 3 and 5 ), how can I make it return the fragment 4 then :) ?

Comment: if you want to reach fragment 4 you can swipe one by one. Or if you whant reach it immediately you can pager.setCurrentItem( num ).

Comment: I am doing that in RecyclerView listner, but then how you said, it's getting it's neighbour 3 and 5 and the current fragment remains 5.

Answer (score 0):

Viewpager indexing starts from zero if you want to load the fourth Fragment then you need to set the position 3.

```
  mPager.setCurrentItem(3); //Load the 4th fragment according to you.(0-3)
```

Comment: My recyclerview starts from 0 too, so when I am loading the index 4 the mPager set the index to 4, I don't think this is the problem, if I do the position - 1 trick when I am pressing the index 0 from RecyclerView it will call the setCurrentItem to -1 and that is not correct.